# Avoid deleting children objects - Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have the following scenario:

One Dose has one or more Nutrients and when the dose is deleted I would like that the nutrients stay in database. Is there any annotation that allows to do that?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a `Dose` object, only the links get invalidated, but the `Nutrient` classes that belong to it stay in the database when you call `dose.deleteFromRealm()`.

So basically that's actually the default use-case.